# Condition within single.php to send an email to the post author

Tags: author, conditional-content, wp-mail

I have this piece of code (below) that checks if the post was modified within the past 7 days. I'd like another piece of code that I can insert where "Needs Updating" is that will send a basic email to the post author that says "Someone was looking at your post and wants it updated" every time the post is viewed (yes, every time).

```
<?php
$timelimit=1 * 604800; //1 week * seconds per day
$post_age = date('U') - get_post_time('U'); ?>
<?php if ($post_age < $timelimit) : ?>
Current
<?php elseif ($post_age > $timelimit) : ?>
Needs Updating
<?php endif; ?>﻿
```

Comment: so what stops you from writting that code?

Comment: @MarkKaplun great question... 
https://github.com/pjeaje/code-snippets/blob/gh-pages/why%20I%20haven't%20written%20that%20code

Comment: to use the last modified time just use... get_the_modified_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [get_the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/) to get the emailaddress of the author of the current post and [the wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)function to send an e-mail

```
<?php
$timelimit=1 * 604800; //1 week * seconds per day
$post_age = date('U') - get_post_time('U');

if ($post_age < $timelimit) : ?>
    // Current
<?php elseif ($post_age > $timelimit) :
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' );
    wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message );
endif;
```